# Is there a way of querying or accessing the structure of a Z3 expression via the API

Tags: z3

I am accessing the managed API from F#. I can construct Z3 expressions using ctx.MkFalse, MkImplies, MkMul etc. but how do i traverse a Z3 expression to discover its structure? Is there something like e.Op or e.IsFalse, e.IsImplies etc.

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at documentation of [Expr.cs](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/class_microsoft_1_1_z3_1_1_expr.html#a74d5773ff130926bd9a932e974372958).

Here is a simple F# example that traverses through an expression:

```ml
let traverse (expr: Expr) =
    printfn "num args: %O" expr.NumArgs
    printfn "children: %A" expr.Args
    printfn "1st child: %O" expr.Args.[0]
    printfn "2nd child: %O" expr.Args.[1]
    printfn "operator: %O" expr.FuncDecl
    printfn "op name: %O" expr.FuncDecl.Name
```

`Expr` class also exposes all [Term Kind Tests including IsTrue, IsAnd, isImplies, etc](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/_expr_8cs_source.html#l00272) which are necessary to discover the structure of an expression. In F# you should define a set of active patterns:

```ml
let (|True|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsTrue then Some() else None
let (|False|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsFalse then Some() else None

let (|And|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsAnd then Some expr.Args else None
let (|Or|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsOr then Some expr.Args else None
let (|Not|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsNot && expr.NumArgs = 1u 
                             then Some(expr.Args.[0]) else None

let (|Iff|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsIff && expr.NumArgs = 2u 
                             then Some(expr.Args.[0], expr.Args.[1]) else None
let (|Implies|_|) (expr: Expr) = if expr.IsImplies && expr.NumArgs = 2u 
                                 then Some(expr.Args.[0], expr.Args.[1]) else None
```

So that you can easily query an expression's structure by pattern matching, even in a recursive way:

```ml
match e with
| True -> (* boolean literal *)
| False -> (* boolean literal *)
| And es -> (* query es; possibly by pattern matching *)
| Or es -> (* query es; possibly by pattern matching *)
| Not e' -> (* query e; possibly by pattern matching *)
| Iff(e1, e2) -> (* query e1, e2; possibly by pattern matching *)
| Implies(e1, e2) -> (* query e1, e2; possibly by pattern matching *)
| _ -> (* Not a boolean expression; do something else *)
```

Comment: Of course, they're all sitting in the Expr class - where i forgot to look. My apologies

Comment: @user1721431: Please consider to accept the answer if it is helpful for you. See [How does accepting an answer work here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).